# how to use resource Dll for different culture

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created the DLL(DynamicResourceDLL) for different culture like below

```
DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart //English
DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart_de_DE 
DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart_es_ES
DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart_fr_FR
```

i added  this `DynamicResourceDLL` dll in my project and try to get the value of key

```
string strCityEnglish = DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart.City //it's working fine
```

but

```
string strCityDe =  DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart_de_DE.City //it's not working
```

i am getting below error

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.
>         Make sure "DynamicResourceDLL.Cart.Cart_de_DE.resources" was correctly embedded or linked
>        into assembly "ExportToExcelFromDataTable" at compile time, 
>       or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

please let me know how to use this Dll for different culture with code or suggest if i made any mistake on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an ASP.NET app ? if thats so, the following resource below will help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ztca10y(v=vs.85).aspx

If windows app, see this sample from below.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352105/Satellite-Assembly-Example-in-Csharp-Step-by-Step

Hope this helps.
Thanks.